# problem with meta commands in TexStudio / copy pdf elsewhere

Tags: texstudio

I've a problem using TexStudio. I've defined a user command to copy the pdf in another directory every time it is re-compiled.
I've done both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, using respectively:

```
cmd /C copy %.pdf D:\folder
bash -c "cp -t ~/folder %.pdf"
```

If i try the command clicking on "Tool > user > Copy PDF" they correctly work.

So i tried to insert this command inside the Meta Command "Build & View" using | txs:///copypdf, but the command is not executed clicking on Build&View. The same problem on Windows and linux...

Am I doing something wrong or what?
Thank you

UPDATE: seems that changing Meta commands is not effective
[image]

The .bat contains:

```
D:
copy D:\babla\blabla\File.pdf D:\Dropbox\blabla\blabla\
```

TeXstudio 2.12.6

Comment: I tried also other command and is the same: launching the command from Tool works, inserting in Meta Command and running Build & View not...

Comment: Meta commands seems to not react from changing definitions

Comment: it works for me (windows 10). what's your TXS version? Does it work if you use `txs:///user0` instead of `txs:///copypdf` (or whichever slot your cmd is on)?

Comment: As a workaround -- if you can't find what's wrong (it should...), you can make use of event triggers (specifically the `?after-command-run`) and throw your cmds into a user macro. It should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I actually don't know how to do a user macro, but is strange that the meta commands do not respond to changes, it isn't?
Have you some ideas about what setting could be wrong?

Comment: Yes, like I said, it works well on my system. So can you attach an image of your settings, and mention what TXS version you are on? Unless you do so, it is impossible for anyone to help debug. Also, if you are ok with user macro way, I can write up an answer pertaining to that. But no guarantees that it will work on your end, considering that the meta commands are not even working as expected..

Comment: @Troy : I updated the question, thank you again. If is not a problem for you I would try the macro

Comment: I might be wrong and this is not quite what was asked, but this looks very much the task of a symlink...

Comment: @Polonio24 Why the need for a `.bat` file? You said you used `cmd /C copy %.pdf D:\folder` but that's not reflected in your image. Anyway, that `.bat` would be invalid once you start up another project in another folder, isn't it? It's better to just stick with `%` that TXS offers. I'll write up an answer with the macro soon.

Comment: .bat was a try once I seen cd D:\ doesn't work on prompt.... when i asked, commands were those reported.
I actually work on a single project
Ty again @Troy

Comment: @gusbrs at least on Windows, dropbox doesn't perceive changes in the target of a symbolic link

Comment: Well, you are talking with a long-time-no-Windows here, so I cannot really comment. But, if my old memories don't trick me, `.lnk` files are essentially text files with the target file path inside. So I can't really get that it doesn't change with the target. If you mean by your comment that your Linux symlink doesn't work on Windows, you are probably correct. Anyway, I must thank you for recalling me how much better things are since I moved to Linux for good.   :)

Comment: @gusbrs No i talk about ntfs symlinks  not .Ink shortcut.... but, for what i know, the problem is the same you said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a User macro implementation of whatever you're trying to achieve, which should hopefully work.

*ps*. I should note that the following macro was written with Windows 10 OS in mind -- do make the appropriate changes for other OS yourself. I'll describe the outputs of each line of the script so hopefully it is easy for you to work out what you need to change.

I am also assuming you are copying your `.pdf` file from your working directory (i.e., where your master/root `.tex` file is) to a folder in D drive called `folder` (i.e., location `D:\folder`)

---

Under `Macros -> Edit Macros`, click `Add` on the bottom left corner of the popup window, and paste the following:

```
%SCRIPT
full_dir = editor.fileName().replace(/\//,"\\")
file_name = full_dir.split(".tex")[0]
system('cmd /C "copy '+file_name+'.pdf D:\\folder"')
```

and give it an event trigger, `?after-command-run`, as shown in the pic below:

[image]

Click `Ok`, then now, whenever a command run has ended (e.g. at the end of a `Build and View` call), this script will automatically be activated, and it should copy to the designated folder.

---

#### A short explanation

- **Line 1**: `editor.filename()` returns a string containing the full directory of the master `.tex` file (which should also be where the `.pdf` is generated). For example, it could be something like

  ```
  C:/Users/.../main.tex
  ```

  (where the `...` is just the relevant paths leading to your `main.tex`.)

  - I then changed all the `/` (forward slash) in the directory string to a `\` (backslash) via regex replacement, because Windows uses backslashes. I'm guessing this isn't the case for other OS, so you can leave the `.replace(...)` statement out in that case.
- **Line 2**: Note also the result of `editor.filename()` leaves a `.tex` extension at the end. So I removed it in this line.
- **Line 3**: Here, the `system` command passes its argument to the command line, and we need to invoke shell explicitly and is **OS-dependent**: (Read the [TXS user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a), under Section 1.3.2, Shell functionality, for more info):

  For Mac OS / Linux:

  ```
  sh -c "<cmds>"
  ```

  For Windows:

  ```
  cmd /C "<cmds>"
  ```

  Lastly, note the `D:\\folder` part of Line 3. Just change that to whatever directory/folder you wish to copy the `.pdf` to. Make sure that folder actually exists.

---

If it is actually successful in running, you should see a message `1 file(s) copied` appear in the Messages box at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly!! Just fix the missing "g" in line 1 (there was in the screen). I really appreciated your clear explaination, it is useful for me. I'm still curious to know why Meta doesn't wok.... but the result is the same

Comment: @Polonio24 Oops, I decided while writing the answer that a global ('g') scope was not required. It's not essential to the answer regardless. From what I can see from your pic, I don't see a reason why it should not work. In other circumstances, I might suggest a resetting of TXS settings, but since the macro works, I would say just stick with this. (It's a cleaner way of achieving what you want anyway, imo.)

Comment: Really without g the script didn't work for me... hower is strange that the Meta didn't work on linux too.... That said, excellent solution, thanks!